# how can I find the history links folder in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

Ugh, IE6. Don't bash me, it's a work thing.

In IE6, how can I find all the links that are in my history folder? I've got it set to keep 20 days of history. However when I see the History bar, there's no entries of 2 Weeks Ago, clearly a bug.

Is there a way I can see what's in this folder without going thru IE6? I want to find a site that I went to about 9 days ago, but the History bar in IE6 doesn't have any entries beyond the Last Week folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default History storage location:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History
```

to view the content, you'll need an **[index.dat viewer](http://www.softwarepatch.com/software/indexdat.html)**.

Comment: Thanks. Must be some other bug then, there's no items in the "2 Weeks Ago" folder, even though the setting is to keep the last 20 days of history. I use IE6 daily, so there must be something in there. I've not cleared out the temp files or anything...

Comment: use the index.dat viewer to check index.dat in your temp folder, this may shed some light on your activities 20 days ago. :)